# Не работает HQL запрос

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-jpa, hql

Что не так с моим HQL запросом? Не возвращает юзера по заданному токену (данный токен в базе данных есть 100%).

**HQL**

```
 @Query("SELECT u FROM User u inner join u.session s where  s.token = :session")
 User getUserBySession(@Param("session") String session);
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne
    private Session session;
```

**Session**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="session")
public class Session {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String token;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
    private User user;
```

Comment: `SELECT u FROM User u inner join u.session s where  s.token = :session` Если запрос верен, то: 1) существует БД с именем `u` 2) В ней есть таблица с именем `session` 3) в ней есть поле `token` 4) в текущей БД есть таблица с именем `User` 5) в одной из этих таблиц есть поле с именем `u`. Если хотя бы одно из этого неверно - то и запрос неправильный.

Comment: @Akina мда, если Вам не сложно, то можете, пожалуйста, показать, как будет выглядеть запрос: из таблицы с именем User взять все даннные пользователя имеющего userid в таблице Session, в которой поле токен будет равно переданному токену?

Comment: Я Hibernate/HQL не использую, а изучать мне лениво. Конвертируйте HQL-ные `User` и `Session` в обычный SQL - тогда подскажу.